# how to use the directive 'name-from-attribute'

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

I am a new hand to JSP. The book on JSP that I read says, *name-from-attribute* must be used with alias. And the named attribute must have been declared as required and does not accept a request-time value. But why do we need *name-from-attribute* in the first place? Could someone give me a simple example as to the use of *name-from-attribute*?

The code is here:

```
....
<%@ attribute name="var" rtexprvalue="false" required="true" %>
<%@ variable name-from-attribute="var" alias="current"
variable-class="java.lang.Object" scope="NESTED" %>
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `name-from-attribute`, then in your jsp page where it uses custom tag library to perform the action, you are free to provide "any variable name". For example-

xyz.tag (version 1, **without** `name-from-attribute`)

```
 ....
 <%@ attribute name="items" rtexprvalue="true" required="true" %>
 <%@ variable name-given="current"
  variable-class="java.lang.Object" scope="NESTED" %>
 ....
```

My jsp page looks like this-

```
 ...
 <%@ taglib prefix="my" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/mytags" %>
 ...

 <my:xyz items="a,b,c,d,e">
    <td>${current}</td>
 ...
```

If you notice above, whatever variable name we used (current) in the tag file is hard-coded. If the name changes, it will break your jsp code.

xyz.tag (version 1, **with** `name-from-attribute`)

```
 ....
 <%@ attribute name="items" rtexprvalue="true" required="true" %>
 <%@ attribute name="var" rtexprvalue="false" required="true" %>
 <%@ variable name-from-attribute="var" alias="current"
  variable-class="java.lang.Object" scope="NESTED" %>
 ....
```

My jsp page looks like this-

```
 ...
 <%@ taglib prefix="my" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/mytags" %>
 ...

 <my:xyz items="a,b,c,d,e" var="anyName">
    <td>${anyName}<</td>
 ...
```

Basically, `name-from-attribute` in the tag file tells the tag processor to pick the actual variable name from the jsp file where custom tag(`my:xyz`) is being used, which in this case **anyName**

**Note:** I am referring [OReilly Java Server Pages book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/jserverpages3/chapter/ch11.pdf)